# Australian travelling to EU before the date of my visa

Tags: visas, schengen, australian-citizens

I can't find the answer to wether as an Australian passport holder I can enter the EU before the date of my long stay visa. my visa is dates 19 of december I want to enter a week before due to my fight is already booked.

Answer (score 4):

As a citizen of a country that does **not** need a **short term** visa (up to 90 days), the extra week before the start of the **long term** visa will be covered by the 90/180 days rule.